# How to make variable visible outside of if-else statment?

Tags: c#

The assignment statement for `rk` can't access variable `xnbb` from "if-else" statement. How can I make it visible? Do I have to create some new method with "return"?

```
var length = Math.Min(xr_arr.Count(), 24);
for (int y = 0; y < 24; y++)
{
    if (xr_arr[y] > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y)))
    {
        var xn = xr_arr[y] - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y));
        int xnbb = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int xnbb = 0;
    }

    var rk = xnbb + 1 * Math.Round(Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (24 - y)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i have to create some new method with "return"?

No, you simply have to declare it outside the `if-else` clause:

```
int xnbb = 0;
if (xr_arr[y] > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y)))
{
    var xn = xr_arr[y] - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y));
    xnbb = 1;
}
else
{
    xnbb = 0;
}
```

Two things to note:

1. As `xnbb` is defaulted to `0`, you can drop your `else` clause completely:

   ```
   int xnbb = 0;
   if (xr_arr[y] > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y)))
   {
       var xn = xr_arr[y] - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y));
       xnbb = 1;
   }
   ```
2. Please give you variables meaningful names. The person who will be debugging this code when you leave will have a terrible time trying to understand what your intentions were.

Answer (score 1):

Reorder your lines like this:

```
            int xnbb;
            if (xr_arr[y] > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y)))
            {
                var xn = xr_arr[y] - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y));
                xnbb = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                xnbb = 0;
            }
            var rk = xnbb + ...
```

You have to declare the variable `xnbb` in a scope where all usages of this variables are contained. In this case it is inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside of a block are available only within that block. You can find more details about variables scope on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) on this.

So in order for you variable to be available in more than one scope, you need to declare that variable in a scope that is an ancestor to both scopes in discussion.

In your case, you can declare the `xnbb` variable right before the `if` statement, as in your case the `for` scope includes the `if` one, so that's the ancestor I was talking above:

```
int xnbb = 0;
if (xr_arr[y] > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y)))
{
    var xn = xr_arr[y] - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-y));
    int xnbb = 1;
}
else
{
   xnbb = 0;
}
```